# Using a DateRangeSelection in a FilterBar and use it to filter the model for my table

Tags: sapui5

```
<fb:FilterBar reset="onReset" search="onSearch">
      <fb:filterItems>
        <fb:FilterItem name="dateRange" label="Date Range" mandatory="true">
          <fb:control>
            <DateRangeSelection id="dateRange" />
          </fb:control>        
        </fb:FilterItem> 
</fb:filterItems>  
</fb:FilterBar>
```

In my onSearch method I get the binding and then use this to set the table's filters:

```
onSearch : function(oEvt) {
    var oFilterBar = oEvt.getSource(), aFilters = [], oParameters;
    aFilters = oFilterBar.getFilters();
    oParameters = oFilterBar.getParameters();

    this.doReload(aFilters, oParameters);
}
```

First issue here is I get 'undefined is not a function' on the call to oFilterBar.getFilters(). oFilterBar itself is not undefined, so that looks OK at first sight. My view includes `xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar"`.

```
doReload : function(aFilters, oParameters) {
    var oTable = this.byId("clockHistoryTable");
    var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter(aFilters);
}
```

I have a hard time connecting the two and figure out how to use the selected range as a filter. My model for the table has a list of items and each item has a field called 'date' which can be used to filter the items based on the selected range. But this field has it's own specific date format yyyymmdd.

Side question, best way to set the default from and to dates for the DateRangeSelection control would be in the controller's init function?

---

Update

After Allen's reponse I did some modifications:

```
doReload : function(aFilters) {
    var oTable = this.byId("clockHistoryTable");
    var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter(aFilters);
},

onReset : function(oEvent) {
    this.doReload();
},

onSearch : function(oEvt) {
    var oFilterBar = oEvt.getSource(), aFilters = [];
    aFilters = oEvt.getParameter("selectionSet");
    this.doReload(aFilters);
},
```

It runs without any errors but when I select a date or range it filters out everything and the table is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no method called `getFilters` for `FilterBar`, only for `SmartFilterBar`. You need to construct your own Filters based on `oEvent.getParameter("selectionSet")`.
- You should set `displayFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"` of `DateRangeSelection` too.
- Yes, you should set default from and to dates of `DateRangeSelection` in the `onInit()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your support Allen. I updated my question with what I've changed meanwhile. Should the name of the filterItem match the name of the field in the model? In my case that would be 'date'. displayFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" is only to set the format in the DateRangeSelection field, right? Because in my case the date value in the model is stored in the format 'yyyyMMdd' (no slashes), so it's not clear to me how that would work by itself..

Comment: oEvt.getParameter("selectionSet") is not the filters you want. You can check it in the Chrome console, it should be DateRangeSelection. You need to construct the array of sap.ui.model.odata.Filter by yourself. The displayFormat will set the format of the DateRangeSelection, so its value will be the same as your data model.

Comment: I'll construct the filter myself and parse the from and to dates into yyyyMMdd, because I don't want the end user to see the selected date in this ugly format. I can see the value in the oEvent.getParameter("selectionSet")[0]._lastValue, is that the right way to access that from/to?

Comment: yes,it is right.Then you can construct sap.ui.model.Filter with a operator sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.BT.